# Container Managed Transaction in EJB

Tags: transactions, ejb

If I mark an EJB to use Container Managed Transaction and from a method of that EJB I do not explicitly use setRollBackOnly() (when an Exception occurs), will that transaction still be flagged for rollback automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends whether or not the exception is an *application exception* (commit by default) or a *system exception* (rollback always).  Application exceptions are most commonly checked exceptions declared on the throws clause, but they can also be declared via the `@ApplicationException` annotation (or corresponding `<application-exception>` element in the ejb-jar.xml).

Comment: So, If an application exception is thrown,and I do not mark it using @ApplicationException or <application-exception> then I need to roll it back by using setRollBackOnly() ?

Comment: @AyanBiswas Yes, but let me reword what you said for accuracy: If an application exception is thrown, then you need to manually rollback the transaction using setRollbackOnly; you can make an exception be an application exception by (1) adding it to the throws clause if the method, (2) annotating it `@ApplicationException`, or (3) usuing `<application-exception>`.

Answer (score 1):

If the thrown exception extends from RuntimeException then the transaction will roll back. If extends from Exception (and not is a RuntimeException) the transaction will commit.

Since ejb 3.0, you can change this behavior using the [@AnnotationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/ApplicationException.html) (or the application-exception deployment descriptor element in ejb-jar.xml file)

Regardless of what class the exception extends, if you marked the class with @AnnotationException(rollback=true) the transaction will never commit, the oposite applies if you marke the exception with @AnnotationException(rollback=false).

Notice that if your code throws an exception, but you catch it before the container can intercept it, the exception will not affect the transaction state.